# Recursive insert of a chain into memory fails

Tags: c++, json, recursion, memory-management, rapidjson

This meight be a long question but i hope someone can help me figuring out whats going wrong.

I am inserting a JSON Object into already allocated Memory with my own Datatype which basically holds a Union with Data and a ptrdiff_t to the next Datatype in 8bit steps.

```
template <typename T>
class BaseType
{
public:
    BaseType();
    explicit BaseType(T& t);
    explicit BaseType(const T& t);

    ~BaseType();
    inline void setNext(const ptrdiff_t& next);
    inline std::ptrdiff_t getNext();
    inline void setData(T& t);
    inline void setData(const T& t);
    inline T getData() const;

protected:
    union DataUnion
    {
        T data;
        ::std::ptrdiff_t size;

        DataUnion()
        {
            memset(this, 0, sizeof(DataUnion));
        } //init with 0
        explicit DataUnion(T& t);
        explicit DataUnion(const T& t);
    } m_data;

    long long m_next;
};
```

The implementation is streight so nothing special happes there just setting/getting the values of the definition. (i'll skip the impl. here)

So here starts the code where something goes wrong:

```
std::pair<void*, void*> Page::insertObject(const rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<>>& value,
         BaseType<size_t>* last)
 {
     //return ptr to the first element
     void* l_ret = nullptr;
     //prev element ptr
     BaseType<size_t>* l_prev = last;

     //position pointer
     void* l_pos = nullptr;
     //get the members
     for (auto it = value.MemberBegin(); it != value.MemberEnd(); ++it)
     {
         switch (it->value.GetType())
         {
             case rapidjson::kNullType:
                 LOG_WARN << "null type: " << it->name.GetString();
                 continue;

             case rapidjson::kFalseType:
             case rapidjson::kTrueType:
                 {
                     l_pos = find(sizeof(BaseType<bool>));

                     void* l_new = new (l_pos) BaseType<bool>(it->value.GetBool());

                     if (l_prev != nullptr)
                         l_prev->setNext(dist(l_prev, l_new));
                 }
                 break;
             case rapidjson::kObjectType:
                 {
                     //pos for the obj id
                     //and insert the ID of the obj
                     l_pos = find(sizeof(BaseType<size_t>));
                     std::string name = it->name.GetString();
                     void* l_new = new (l_pos) BaseType<size_t>(common::FNVHash()(name));

                     if (l_prev != nullptr)
                         l_prev->setNext(dist(l_prev, l_new));
                     //TODO something strange happens here!

                     // pass the objid Object to the insertobj!
                     // now recursive insert the obj
                     // the second contains the last element inserted
                     // l_pos current contains the last inserted element and get set to the
                     // last element of the obj we insert
                     l_pos = (insertObject(it->value, reinterpret_cast<BaseType<size_t>*>(l_new)).second);
                 }
                 break;

             case rapidjson::kArrayType:
                 {//skip this at the moment till the bug is fixed
                 }
                 break;

             case rapidjson::kStringType:
                 {
                     // find pos where the string fits
                     // somehow we get here sometimes and it does not fit!
                     // which cant be since we lock the whole page
                     l_pos = find(sizeof(StringType) + strlen(it->value.GetString()));

                     //add the String Type at the pos of the FreeType
                     auto* l_new = new (l_pos) StringType(it->value.GetString());
                     if (l_prev != nullptr)
                         l_prev->setNext(dist(l_prev, l_new));
                 }
                 break;

             case rapidjson::kNumberType:
                 {
                     //doesnt matter since long long and double are equal on x64
                     //find pos where the string fits
                     l_pos = find(sizeof(BaseType<long long>));

                     void* l_new;
                     if (it->value.IsInt())
                     {
                         //insert INT
                         l_new = new (l_pos) BaseType<long long>(it->value.GetInt64());
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         //INSERT DOUBLE
                         l_new = new (l_pos) BaseType<double>(it->value.GetDouble());
                     }
                     if (l_prev != nullptr)
                         l_prev->setNext(dist(l_prev, l_new));
                 }
                 break;
             default:
                 LOG_WARN << "Unknown member Type: " << it->name.GetString() << ":" << it->value.GetType();
                 continue;
         }
         //so first element is set now, store it to return it.
         if(l_ret == nullptr)
         {
             l_ret = l_pos;
         }
         //prev is the l_pos now so cast it to this;
         l_prev = reinterpret_cast<BaseType<size_t>*>(l_pos);
     }
     //if we get here its in!
     return{ l_ret, l_pos };
 }
```

I am starting to insert like this:

```
auto firstElementPos = insertObject(value.MemberBegin()->value, nullptr).first;
```

While `value.MemberBegin()->value` is Object to be inserted and `->name` holds the Name of the object. In the case below its Person and everything between `{}`.

The problem is, if i insert a JSON Object which has one Object inside like so:

```
"Person":
{
    "age":25,
    "double": 23.23,
    "boolean": true,
    "double2": 23.23,
    "firstInnerObj":{
        "innerDoub": 12.12
    }   
}
```

It works properly and i can reproduce the Object. But if i have more inner objects like so:

```
"Person":
{
    "age":25,
    "double": 23.23,
    "boolean": true,
    "double2": 23.23,
    "firstInnerObj":{
        "innerDoub": 12.12
    },
    "secondInnerObj":{
        "secInnerDoub": 12.12
    }
}
```

It fails and i lose data so i think that my recursion goes wrong but i dont see why. If you need any more informations let me know. Meight take a look [here](https://github.com/BennX/jim-db/blob/master/src/page/page.cpp) and the [client here](https://github.com/BennX/JIM-DB-Java-Client).

The test.json need to contain a json object like above. And the find only need to contain `{"oid__":2}` to get the second object that was inserted.

---

I could track the issue down to the Point where i recreate the Object recursively in the code. Some of the Nextpointers seem to be incorrect:

```
    void* Page::buildObject(const size_t& hash, void* start, rapidjson::Value& l_obj,
                            rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>& aloc)
    {
        //get the meta information of the object type
        //to build it
        auto& l_metaIdx = meta::MetaIndex::getInstance();
        //get the meta dataset
        auto& l_meta = l_metaIdx[hash];

        //now we are already in an object here with l_obj!
        auto l_ptr = start;
        for (auto it = l_meta->begin(); it != l_meta->end(); ++it)
        {
            //create the name value
            rapidjson::Value l_name(it->name.c_str(), it->name.length(), aloc);
            //create the value we are going to add
            rapidjson::Value l_value;
            //now start building it up again
            switch (it->type)
            {
                case meta::OBJECT:
                    {
                        auto l_data = static_cast<BaseType<size_t>*>(l_ptr);
                        //get the hash to optain the metadata
                        auto l_hash = l_data->getData();
                        //set to object and create the inner object
                        l_value.SetObject();

                        //get the start pointer which is the "next" element
                        //and call recursive
                        l_ptr = static_cast<BaseType<size_t>*>(buildObject(l_hash,
                                                               (reinterpret_cast<char*>(l_data) + l_data->getNext()), l_value, aloc));
                    }
                    break;
                case meta::ARRAY:
                    {
                        l_value.SetArray();
                        auto l_data = static_cast<ArrayType*>(l_ptr);
                        //get the hash to optain the metadata
                        auto l_size = l_data->size();
                        l_ptr = buildArray(l_size, static_cast<char*>(l_ptr) + l_data->getNext(), l_value, aloc);
                    }
                    break;
                case meta::INT:
                    {
                        //create the data
                        auto l_data = static_cast<BaseType<long long>*>(l_ptr);
                        //with length attribute it's faster ;)
                        l_value = l_data->getData();
                    }
                    break;
                case meta::DOUBLE:
                    {
                        //create the data
                        auto l_data = static_cast<BaseType<double>*>(l_ptr);
                        //with length attribute it's faster ;)
                        l_value = l_data->getData();
                    }
                    break;
                case meta::STRING:
                    {
                        //create the data
                        auto l_data = static_cast<StringType*>(l_ptr);
                        //with length attribute it's faster
                        l_value.SetString(l_data->getString()->c_str(), l_data->getString()->length(), aloc);
                    }
                    break;
                case meta::BOOL:
                    {
                        //create the data
                        auto l_data = static_cast<BaseType<bool>*>(l_ptr);
                        l_value = l_data->getData();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            l_obj.AddMember(l_name, l_value, aloc);
            //update the lptr
            l_ptr = static_cast<char*>(l_ptr) + static_cast<BaseType<size_t>*>(l_ptr)->getNext();
        }
        //return the l_ptr which current shows to the next lement. //see line above
        return l_ptr;
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, I lost faith at `std::pair<void*, void*>` (WTF). I stopped caring when it wasn't [selfcontained](http://sscce.org) and I swiftly went for protective downvotes at the `reinterpret_cast<char*>` whatevers.

Comment: Seriously. What is the question about. If your allocator/free-list thingy has a bug, post **that** as a self-contained question. If not, drop the allocator from the question etc.

Comment: @sehe i am sorry for the freelist thingy that should be there i dropped it. I am somehow losing the second object or the end of the first so the chain somehow corrupts there.

Comment: I went "full pitbull" mode there ([20 files changed, 215 insertions(+), 82 deletions(-)](https://github.com/sehe/jim-db/commit/df5ef477b8ba58533179aed389198f212cf35bae)). Now how to get the SSCCE test case?

Comment: @sehe thank you very very much about the "full pitbull"! One second i'll add the Client which i use to dump data in and retrive data to github. https://github.com/BennX/JIM-DB-Java-Client Would you maybe add a PR for your changes?  Adding information to the question about the jsons of test and find

Comment: No need anymore, I already had this: but it's working fine for sofar: https://github.com/sehe/jim-db/commit/6b69375c9e990d8eccd7c448f4a8d60a78767b5a

Comment: No, no PR because I actually butchered all the winsock stuff. Just to get a tester to compile/link

Comment: Okay thanks ill take a look at the changes and see which ill take. I am sorry if it is somewhere a mess. If we get this working ill sure reward this. I am sure you dont need that but i am thankfull for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94926/discussion-between-sehe-and-bennx).

Comment: I think i could track it down to the get next when I call recursive with char* l_ptr + l_ptr->getNext(). Here it does return 4 while the data type is already 16 big so there is some issue I think which causes in a wrong cast and a wrong hash.

Comment: i found it! at the build i did not return the last ptr i returned the last->next ptr and called the ->next on that which caused a stepover... now it works properly! thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After houers and houres of debugging i found the small issue which causes this. The method which builds up the Object after it was inserted returns a pointer to the [actuall last `element->next` which was inserted](https://github.com/BennX/jim-db/blob/7680dbd7f541be12118b31c16cd06c954bbbe144/src/page/page.cpp#L664) and after the switch case i [did call the `->next` again](https://github.com/BennX/jim-db/blob/7680dbd7f541be12118b31c16cd06c954bbbe144/src/page/page.cpp#L661) which causes a loss of data because it scipped one element in the single chained list.

The Fix to this is to put the line

```
l_ptr = static_cast<char*>(l_ptr) + static_cast<BaseType<size_t>*>(l_ptr)->getNext();
```

Only into the switch cases where it is not an Object or Array. [Fix Commit](https://github.com/BennX/jim-db/commit/747cfc9f1f34e9650b7af2c7d99348208c0206c8) This actually also gave me the fix for an Issue with inserting Array.

Of cause the real issue could not know someone here who did not took a deep look into the code but i still want to show the fix here. Thanks to @sehe who helped alot with figuring out whats going wrong here.